# SQL how to get the max price of the 33% cheapests products

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to to  get the max price of the 33% cheapests products. My idea is like this. Of course, this code is just an example. I need to use subqueries.

```
select max((select price from products order by preco limit 33%  ))  as result from products
```

For example

```
  product_id    price
      1          10
      2          50
      3          100
      4          400
      5          900
      6         8999
```

I need I query that returns 50, since 33% of the rows are 2, and the max value of the 2(33%) of the rows is 50.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you would use window functions:

```
select avg(precio)
from (select p.*, row_number() over (order by precio) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from products p
     ) p
where seqnum <= 0.33 * cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there are multiple approaches to this but here is how I would do it.

1. Simply get a count on the table. This will let me pick the max price of the cheapest 33% of products. Let's say it returned `n` records. Third of that would be `n/3`. Here you can either round up or down but needs to be rounded in case of a fraction.
2. Then my query would be something like `SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET n/3`. This would return me a single record with minimal calculations and look ups on MySQL side.

Comment: **Here you can either round up or down but needs to be rounded in case of a fraction.** I used `n/3` in the query to indicate to you to use the value of `n/3` there

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL versions under MySQL 8.0 you can use MySQL's user variables to simulate/emulate a `ROW_NUMBER()`

**Query**

```
 SELECT 
    t.product_id
  , t.price
  , (@ROW_NUMBER := @ROW_NUMBER + 1) AS ROW_NUMBER
 FROM 
  t
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @ROW_NUMBER := 0) AS init_user_variable
 ORDER BY 
  t.price ASC
```

**Result**

```
| product_id | price | ROW_NUMBER |
| ---------- | ----- | ---------- |
| 1          | 10    | 1          |
| 2          | 50    | 2          |
| 3          | 100   | 3          |
| 4          | 400   | 4          |
| 5          | 900   | 5          |
| 6          | 8999  | 6          |
```

When we get the ROW_NUMBER we can use that in combination with `ROW_NUMBER <= CEIL(((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t) * 0.33));`

Which works like this

`(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t)` => Counts and returns 6 
`(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t) * 0.33)` Calculates 33% from 6 which is 1.98 and returns it 
`CEIL(..)` Return the smallest integer value that is greater than or equal to 1.98 which is 2 in this case
`ROW_NUMBER <= 2` So the last filter is this.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
     a.product_id
   , a.price
FROM (
 SELECT 
    t.product_id
  , t.price
  , (@ROW_NUMBER := @ROW_NUMBER + 1) AS ROW_NUMBER
 FROM 
  t
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @ROW_NUMBER := 0) AS init_user_variable
 ORDER BY 
  t.price ASC
) AS a
WHERE  
 ROW_NUMBER <= CEIL(((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t) * 0.33));
```

**Result**

```
| product_id | price |
| ---------- | ----- |
| 1          | 10    |
| 2          | 50    |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qy8tevDwJmuV3GtdTCFJdG/0)

To get get the max it's just as simple as adding `ORDER BY a.price DESC LIMIT 1`

**Query**

```
SELECT 
     a.product_id
   , a.price
FROM (
 SELECT 
    t.product_id
  , t.price
  , (@ROW_NUMBER := @ROW_NUMBER + 1) AS ROW_NUMBER
 FROM 
  t
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @ROW_NUMBER := 0) AS init_user_variable
 ORDER BY 
  t.price ASC
) AS a
WHERE  
 ROW_NUMBER <= CEIL(((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t) * 0.33))
ORDER BY 
  a.price DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

**Result**

```
| product_id | price |
| ---------- | ----- |
| 2          | 50    |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qy8tevDwJmuV3GtdTCFJdG/1)

Answer (score 0):

If your version supports window functions, you can use [`NTILE(3)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_ntile) to divide the rows into three groups ordered by `price`. The first group will contain (about) "33%" of lowest prices. Then you just need to select the MAX value from that group:

```
with cte as (
  select price, ntile(3) over (order by price) as ntl
  from products
)
select max(price)
from cte
where ntl = 1
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/61sCDy2e7h9tb527Af26KH/0)

Prior to MySQL 8.0 I would use a temprary table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column:

```
create temporary table tmp (
  rn int auto_increment primary key,
  price decimal(10,2)
);
insert into tmp(price)
  select price from products order by price;

set @max_rn = (select max(rn) from tmp);

select price
from tmp
where rn <= @max_rn / 3
order by rn desc
limit 1;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gR2Kj4zUEm8ziYt3aD4UXh/0)